# Cannot use angular material datepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material

I try to use angular material datepicker.

The component html file where I try to use it:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

`app.module.ts` file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NavComponent } from './components/pages/dashboard/nav/nav.component';
import { DefaultComponent } from './components/pages/dashboard/default/default.component';
import { ChartComponent } from './components/pages/dashboard/chart/chart.component';
import { UploadComponent } from './components/pages/dashboard/upload/upload.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    NavComponent,
    DefaultComponent,
    ChartComponent,
    UploadComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The error I get: `error NG8001: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element`.

But, as the angular material datepicker doucumentation states, I only need to import:
`import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';` as I did.

**edit**:

After fixing imports,
I get no errors, but also don't get it work.
All I see is:
[image]

- marked by arrow - is the place where the datepicker is placed. But I cant see it work. why?

Answer (score 0):

You need below modules also

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: Error: `Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but 
could not be resolved to an NgModule class.`

Comment: After reset `ng serve` it worked. But no fully. Look at edit.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrapped the date picker in a `<mat-form-field>`, you must also import

```
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

and add it to your `imports` array,

as seen here in the full example of the snippet you have copied and pasted.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/vnydardxnkq?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Got error: `ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field-module.d.ts:8:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.`

Comment: After reset ng serve it worked. But no fully. Look at edit.